# Display formatted decimal numbers in Primefaces 4

Tags: jsf, primefaces, converters

I have a database table with a float field and I want to display it through Primefaces.
I want to display the numbers formatted as (one thousand, for example): 1.000,00
I tried:

```
<p:column sortBy="#{item.value}" filterBy="#{item.value}">
  <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="#{epoBundle.ListUpbTitle_value}"/>
  </f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{item.value}"/>
<f:convertNumber pattern="#0.000" locale="pt_BR"/>
</p:column>
```

But got:
    /WEB-INF/include/entity/upb/List.xhtml @80,55  **Parent not an instance of ValueHolder: org.primefaces.component.column.Column**@13ec99d0

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`f:convertNumber` must be inside `h:outputText`.

```
<h:outputText value="#{item.value}">
    <f:convertNumber pattern="#0.000" locale="pt_BR"/>
</h:outputText>
```

Comment: Ok. It worked, but how can I mask the value to be displayed as, for example: 1.000,32 ? Thanks Simon!

Comment: Just press "Ask Question" button to ask a new question?

Comment: Ok, I can do it... again (see the beginning of my question): "I want to display the NUMBERS FORMATTED as (one thousand, for example): 1.000,00"...