# Masking numbers in PrimeFaces datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, number-formatting

Related to the question [Display formatted decimal numbers in Primefaces 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730809/display-formatted-decimal-numbers-in-primefaces-4/19731795#19731795), how can I display - in a PrimeFaces datatable - a number masked like this:

1.987.654,32

The original data, which are read from a float column in SQLServer database table, is (e.g.):

1987654.32

I've tried the code below, but no success:

```
<p:column sortBy="#{item.value}" filterBy="#{item.value}">
  <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="#{epoBundle.ListUpbTitle_value}"/>
  </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{item.value}">
      <f:convertNumber pattern="#0.000" locale="pt_BR"/>
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct `pattern` for the `<f:convertNumber .../>` you want is: `###,###.000`. You can read more about decimal formatting here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

Bonus: for different masks, you can use other locales: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11836387/1362049

Comment: Simon, the mask you provided is wrong related to the one I asked for. But no problem, I figured out: it should be: '###.###,00'. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: Just remember that `.` and `,` are placeholders.